# Checking if queue contains object

Tags: java

For a `java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue`

By Java specification, for a method `contains(Object o)`

If I have previously inserted a new object like:

```
Task task = new Task("taskname", "somevalue"); 
queue.put(task);
```

on it. And later try to do this:

```
Task task = new Task("taskname", "somevalue"); 
queue.contains(task);
```

Since BlockingQueue is just an interface, by Java specification, should this return true or not?

The `Task` class is `Serializable` so the comparison will be based on field values right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The behavior depends on if `Task` class overrides `equals` method. Depending on the logic of `equals` method, these two Tasks `may/may not` be equal.

From the [Java docs of Blocking queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29)

> boolean contains(Object o)
>
> Returns true if this queue contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this queue contains at least one element e such that o.equals(e).

If the `equals` method is not overridden, then Java will use the [`equals` method of `Object`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/Object.java#Object.equals%28java.lang.Object%29) for equality check(which checks if object references are equal).

```
   public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

Since these are two distinct objects, so object reference id will be different and hence `contains` will return `false`.

Comment: To be clear, `equals` is the method responsible for determining if two objects are equal. Many data structures require `hashCode` to be equal among equal objects, but two objects with the same hash code might not be equal to one another. The default implementation of `equals` does not involve hash codes but instead the internal object ids, such that two objects are only equal if they refer to exactly the same object instance.

Comment: @JeffBowman thanks for pointing out the discrepancy in my answer. I have made the correction.

Answer (score 1):

> Since BlockingQueue is just an interface, by Java specification,
>   should this return true or not?

This is a weird question. As long as `queue` object is created, it should behave as promised by its interface(`BlockingQueue`).

Interface is abstract in that it cannot be instantiated by itself, but it's a common contract for all objects created by those classes that implement it.

As for your concreate question, whether `queue.contains(task)` return `true` depends on how class `Task` defines its `equals` method.

Comment: While other answers focus on the `queue.contains` problem, I think the bigger problem is the OP doesn't really understand the conception of interface.

Answer (score 0):

Thats depends on what is the logic that you write in the `contains()` method. When you try to instantiate `BlockingQueue<Object>` is forces you to implement few methods and `contains()` is ojne of them.

```
BlockingQueue<Object> a = new BlockingQueue<Object>()
{

    @Override
    public Object remove()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object poll()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object element()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object peek()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int size()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Object> iterator()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] toArray()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T[] toArray( T[] a )
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsAll( Collection< ? > c )
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll( Collection< ? extends Object> c )
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeAll( Collection< ? > c )
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean retainAll( Collection< ? > c )
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean add( Object e )
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean offer( Object e )
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void put( Object e ) throws InterruptedException
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean offer( Object e, long timeout, TimeUnit unit ) throws InterruptedException
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Object take() throws InterruptedException
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object poll( long timeout, TimeUnit unit ) throws InterruptedException
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int remainingCapacity()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove( Object o )
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains( Object o )
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int drainTo( Collection< ? super Object> c )
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int drainTo( Collection< ? super Object> c, int maxElements )
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
};
```